# More than/less than function in dplyr not working (or I'm not getting why they're not)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using the flights dataset from the nycflights123 library. Every time I try to arrange these flights by delay time, it does *the opposite* and just gives me data thats not greater than 10.

```
  least_delayed <- arrange(flights,
                             arr_delay >=10,
                             dep_delay >=10)
```

[image: Should be greater than 10, its less than 10 for both variables.]

Equally trivial, when I try to arrange by <=10, I once again get the opposite of less than 10:

```
least_delayed <- arrange(flights,
                         arr_delay <=10,
                         dep_delay <=10)
```

[image: Should be less than 10. Variables are more than 10.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrange` orders the data. I think you are looking for `filter` -

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)

flights %>%
  filter(arr_delay >=10,
         dep_delay >=10)
```

Comment: That answers that question. My only standing question is that I was trying to answer this in the book I'm using, which is focusing on the "arrange" function:

"Sort flights to find the fastest flights."

I get that you can just click the top header of the "air_time" variable of the dataset to find it that way, but is there another way I'm not thinking of besides the answer you illustrated?

Comment: To answer that question you can `arrange` the data and select the last row. `flights %>% filter(!is.na(air_time)) %>% arrange(air_time) %>% slice_tail(n = 1) %>%  select(air_time)`

Comment: I presume you mean `slice_head` (or plain `slice`) instead of `slice_tail`, since the flights will be in order of air_time and "fastest" sounds like they mean "shortest," which will come first in the sorted data.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `%>% arrange(arr_delay <=10)`, `arr_delay <=10` is evaluated as FALSE/TRUE or 0/1 for each row of `flights`. FALSE comes first, which is why you are getting results in the opposite order you expected.

In the example below, `smol` is the result of a test `x <= 3`. It's FALSE for 4 and 5, so when we arrange by `smol` those come first.

```
data.frame(x = 1:5) %>%
  mutate(smol = x <= 3) %>%
  arrange(smol)

  x  smol
1 4 FALSE
2 5 FALSE
3 1  TRUE
4 2  TRUE
5 3  TRUE
```

If you want the ten shortest flights, try:

```
flights %>%
  arrange(air_time) %>%
  slice(1:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

With more than one column, we may either use `across` or `if_all` and create the logical condition to `filter` when both column conditions are met

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)

flights %>%
  filter(across(c(arr_delay, dep_delay), ~ . >=10))
```